# How to trace the evaluation of all forms in the body of an Elisp function

Tags: debugging

When working with bash scripts, when something is not behaving the way you want it to, you can add a

```
set -x
```

and the next time you run the script you can see the methods and the sub methods being called in real time.

Is there an equivalent switch in "elisp"?

Comment: I don't know anything like that, but if you want to see the calls for a  few specific functions you can use `M-x trace-function`. See also "Debugging lisp programs" in the elisp manual.

Comment: @JeanPierre: Please consider adding that info as an answer.

Comment: The previous title could not be understood without context. I hope you accept the new one.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by sub methods. Do you mean that all functions called in the function body should also be instrumented for tracing? I am afraid that this clutters up the tracing buffer quite much.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to me if all functions of package robe.el was instrumented.

Answer (score 5):

The *Elisp debugger* doesn't provide a trace, but it does let you investigate (and even affect) the evaluation of Lisp code on the fly.

- You can enter the debugger, to walk or skip through any function, using `M-x debug-on-entry`.
- You can put breakpoints, which enter the debugger, at any place in Lisp source code, just by adding `(debug)`. (See `C-h f debug` for info about optional args.)
- You can automatically open the debugger when an error is raised, by setting variable `debug-on-error` to non-`nil`.

See the Elisp manual, starting with node [Invoking the Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Invoking-the-Debugger.html). In Emacs you can get to that by `C-h i`, choosing Elisp, then `i debug RET`.

There is also Edebug, whose use is a bit different. For that, you "instrument" particular functions whose evaluation in calls you want to investigate. You can read about it here: `C-h i` then choose Elisp, then `g edebug RET`. That takes you to node [Edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) of the Elisp manual.

Comment: Now we have [one;-)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53617/2370).

Comment: a guy debugging on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odkYXXYOxpo

Answer (score 3):

The function `edebug-instrument-for-tracing` as defined in the following Elisp snippet works similar to `edebug-defun`.
But, instead of instrumenting stuff for `edebug` it prepares it for tracing into the buffer `*edebug-trace*`.

```el
(defun edebug-untrace (form)
  "Remove tracing instructions from FORM."
  (if (consp form)
      (if (eq (car form) 'edebug-tracing)
          (edebug-untrace (caddr form))
        (cons (edebug-untrace (car form))
              (edebug-untrace (cdr form))))
    form))

(defcustom edebug-trace-print-level 3
  "`print-level' for `edebug-make-trace-form'."
  :type 'integer
  :group 'edebug)

(defcustom edebug-trace-print-length 5
  "`print-length' for `edebug-make-trace-form'."
  :type 'integer
  :group 'edebug)

(defun edebug-make-trace-form (form)
  "Prepare FORM for tracing."
  `(edebug-tracing ,(let ((print-level edebug-trace-print-level)
                          (print-length edebug-trace-print-length))
                      (prin1-to-string (edebug-untrace form)))
                   ,form))

(defun edebug-make-trace-enter-wrapper (forms)
  "Prepare function with FORMS for tracing."
  (if edebug-def-name
      `(edebug-tracing ,(format "%S%S"
                                edebug-def-name
                                (nreverse edebug-def-args))
                       ,@forms)
    `(progn ,@forms)))

(defun edebug-instrument-for-tracing ()
  "Like `edebug-defun' but instruments for tracing."
  (interactive)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'edebug-make-enter-wrapper)
             (lambda (forms)
               (edebug-make-trace-enter-wrapper forms)))
            ((symbol-function 'edebug-make-before-and-after-form)
             (lambda (before-index form after-index)
               (edebug-make-trace-form form)))
            ((symbol-function 'edebug-make-after-form)
             (lambda (form after-index)
               (edebug-make-trace-form form))))
    (edebug-defun)))
```

For testing, put point into the following form and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `edebug-instrument-for-tracing`.

```el
(let ((i 0))
  (while (< i 2)
    (message "i=%d" i)
    (setq i (1+ i))))
```

You get an `*edebug-trace*` buffer with the following output.
Each form is printed before and after its evaluation.
The result of the evaluation of the form is also printed.

```el
{ (let ((i 0)) (while (< i 2) (message "i=%d" i) (setq i ...)))
:{ (while (< i 2) (message "i=%d" i) (setq i (1+ i)))
::{ (< i 2)
:::{ i
:::} i result: 0
::} (< i 2) result: t
::{ (message "i=%d" i)
:::{ i
:::} i result: 0
::} (message "i=%d" i) result: i=0
::{ (setq i (1+ i))
:::{ (1+ i)
::::{ i
::::} i result: 0
:::} (1+ i) result: 1
::} (setq i (1+ i)) result: 1
::{ (< i 2)
:::{ i
:::} i result: 1
::} (< i 2) result: t
::{ (message "i=%d" i)
:::{ i
:::} i result: 1
::} (message "i=%d" i) result: i=1
::{ (setq i (1+ i))
:::{ (1+ i)
::::{ i
::::} i result: 1
:::} (1+ i) result: 2
::} (setq i (1+ i)) result: 2
::{ (< i 2)
:::{ i
:::} i result: 2
::} (< i 2) result: nil
:} (while (< i 2) (message "i=%d" i) (setq i (1+ i))) result: nil
} (let ((i 0)) (while (< i 2) (message "i=%d" i) (setq i ...))) result: nil
```

Note that this is a kind of simple prototype-implementation. It is not very efficient. It may be that tracing becomes a bit slow on deeply nested functions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything like that, but if you want to see the calls (including parameters and return value) for a few specific functions you can use the `trace-function` command.

Here's its docstring:

> (trace-function FUNCTION &optional BUFFER CONTEXT)
>
> Trace calls to function FUNCTION.
>
> With a prefix argument, also prompt for the trace buffer (default
>   ‘trace-buffer’), and a Lisp expression CONTEXT.
>
> Tracing a function causes every call to that function to insert
>   into BUFFER Lisp-style trace messages that display the function’s
>   arguments and return values.  It also evaluates CONTEXT, if that is
>   non-nil, and inserts its value too.  For example, you can use this
>   to track the current buffer, or position of point.
>
> ...
>
> To stop tracing a function, use ‘untrace-function’ or ‘untrace-all’.